# What kind of noise is this?

Tags: python, random, numpy, noise

What kind of noise does `numpy.random.random((NX,NY))` create? White noise? If it makes a difference, I sometimes instead make 3D or 1D noise (argument is `(NX,NY,NZ)` or `(N,)`).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
>>> help(numpy.random.random)
Help on built-in function random_sample:

random_sample(...)
    random_sample(size=None)

    Return random floats in the half-open interval [0.0, 1.0).

    Results are from the "continuous uniform" distribution over the
    stated interval.  To sample :math:`Unif[a, b), b > a` multiply
    the output of `random_sample` by `(b-a)` and add `a`::

      (b - a) * random_sample() + a
    ...
```

As the help says, `numpy.random.random()` supplies a "continuous uniform" distribution.

For a "Gaussian/white noise" distribution use [`numpy.random.normal()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.normal.html).

Comment: Thanks; I might try those later to see if it makes my test results easier to interpret. For now, I just needed to know what to call it, so I could describe it semi-intelligently in a paper.

Answer (score 1):

White noise has a mean of 0 and standard deviation of 1. Since,

```
std(numpy.random.random(1000000)) ≈ 0.2889
```

and

```
mean(numpy.random.random(1000000)) ≈ 0.5
```

numpy.random.random() does not create white noise; per definition. But there is nothing that could create white noise, since it is a theoretical construct.

Comment: The definition of white noise is that it has a flat power spectrum. The marginal distribution of the samples is irrelevant.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_noise

Comment: As per @RobertKern's comment, in the dsp sense, _white_ just means the samples are all uncorrelated with one another, or the auto-correlation function is a delta function, or the power spectrum is flat (all of which are equivalent).

Comment: I think a flat power spectrum (if I understand correctly what that means) would be exactly what I want--in this test, I'm looking at the spectral convergence rate of a Gauss-Seidel smoother, and the continuous uniform distribution drops off at high and low frequencies. I only have a week left to work on this, and other things take precedence, but I might try to generate better noise  later in the week. Thanks.